How to combine multiple datafrmes by rows and columns?
I have a list with multiple squared dataframes each representing the economy of a country. I would like to combine all the dataframes in a single dataframe with the data of each country on the diagonal cells corresponding to the same column and row names.
Here is a toy setup:
# toy IO
df1 <- data.frame (a1=rnorm(3),
                 b1=rnorm(3)+2,
                 c1=rnorm(3)*2)
rownames(df1) <- colnames(df1)
df2 <- data.frame (a2=rnorm(3),
                   b2=rnorm(3)+5,
                   c2=rnorm(3)*5)
rownames(df2) <- colnames(df2)
df3 <- data.frame (a3=rnorm(3),
                   b3=rnorm(3)+10,
                   c3=rnorm(3)*10)
rownames(df3) <- colnames(df3)

IO <- list(df1,df2,df3)

# initialize the MRIO
# 3*3=9
bigmat <- matrix(NA, 9,9)
dim(bigmat)
bigmat <- as.data.frame(bigmat)
# input row and col names
colnames(bigmat) <- c(colnames(df1),colnames(df2),colnames(df3))
rownames(bigmat) <- colnames(bigmat)

And here what I ideally want. Of course in the original problem I have 214 variables by 25 dataframes, so I would like to have an automated solution.


why not simply dplyr::bind_rows(IO) or plyr::rbind.fill(IO)???

Use bdiag in Matrix.  Note that Matrix comes with R so it does not need to be installed. If you prefer a sparse matrix of class "dgCMatrix" then omit the outer as.matrix. If it is known that the components of IO have the same dimensions unlist can be omitted (but it won't hurt if you leave it in).
library(Matrix)
m <- as.matrix(do.call(bdiag, lapply(IO, as.matrix)))
rownames(m) <- unlist(sapply(IO, rownames))
colnames(m) <- unlist(sapply(IO, colnames))
m

adiag from the magic package also works:
library(magic)

m <- do.call(adiag, lapply(IO, as.matrix))
rownames(m) <- unlist(sapply(IO, rownames))
colnames(m) <- unlist(sapply(IO, colnames))

m

Either of the above approaches give
           a1       b1         c1         a2       b2         c2         a3        b3        c3
a1 -0.1513960 1.228208  0.8691008  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
b1  0.3297912 2.286549  1.6003537  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
c1 -3.2273228 0.779488 -0.3278619  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
a2  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  1.2429188 5.403631  0.1442195  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
b2  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000 -0.9343851 4.113563 -2.1606490  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
c2  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.3937087 3.681062  8.4493626  0.0000000  0.000000  0.000000
a3  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  1.2283928  9.479131 16.858872
b3  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.2760235 11.623203 -2.416898
c3  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.000000  0.0000000 -1.0489755  8.929932 -4.682005

 

Note
IO <- list(
  data.frame(
    a1 = c(-0.15139596233578126, 0.3297912007577342, -3.2273228297675036),
    b1 = c(1.2282082287538416, 2.286548567354287, 0.7794880176338643),
    c1 = c(0.8691007542260557, 1.6003537316708585, -0.32786193728595037),
    row.names = c("a1", "b1", "c1")
  ),
  data.frame(
    a2 = c(1.2429187749373165, -0.9343850580551597, 0.39370865221579254),
    b2 = c(5.403631455697291, 4.113563283583199, 3.6810623964633677),
    c2 = c(0.14421954258220337, -2.1606489673566616, 8.449362593227988),
    row.names = c("a2", "b2", "c2")
  ),
  data.frame(
    a3 = c(1.228392782136422, 0.27602347826588974, -1.0489755044730924),
    b3 = c(9.479130656167058, 11.623202521730665, 8.929931770655703),
    c3 = c(16.858872442051617, -2.416897677389497, -4.682004786404757),
    row.names = c("a3", "b3", "c3")
  )
)


I get an error from this approach: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'unname': invalid type "character" in '.m2sparse.checking'

Copy and paste the input in the Note at end and then run the code and you should get the output shown.  I am using R version 4.4.0 Patched (2024-04-24 r86483 ucrt)"

Have added unlist in case the question's example does not fully reflect what you want and your actual situation is that the component matrices do not have the same dimensions.

This is a good time for a for() loop. You can assign to your big matrix by the row and column names of the data frames in your list, IO.
for (dat in IO) bigmat[rownames(dat), colnames(dat)] <- dat

bigmat
#            a1        b1        c1          a2       b2         c2         a3        b3        c3
# a1 -0.7022840 0.8113511  0.947473          NA       NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
# b1 -1.3965466 1.1572675  1.251534          NA       NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
# c1 -0.7046801 2.4452599 -1.759129          NA       NA         NA         NA        NA        NA
# a2         NA        NA        NA -0.02525984 4.706425 -2.7166644         NA        NA        NA
# b2         NA        NA        NA -0.99340937 4.087659 -2.2857446         NA        NA        NA
# c2         NA        NA        NA  1.14106869 6.175546 -0.5993501         NA        NA        NA
# a3         NA        NA        NA          NA       NA         NA 2.11147819 10.124772 -1.458151
# b3         NA        NA        NA          NA       NA         NA 0.95736185  8.755218  2.136663
# c3         NA        NA        NA          NA       NA         NA 0.01153827  9.380493  2.745363

Alternatively if you want to do it a more idiomatic way for R, you can achieve the same output with Reduce():
Reduce(
    \(bigmat, dat) {
        bigmat[rownames(dat), colnames(dat)] <- dat
        bigmat
    },
    IO,
    init = bigmat
)
### ^^ same results

I think your question implies the row and columns are already in the correct order in each data frame. Nevertheless, an advantage of this approach is that regardless of order, we're joining on names, so if one of your data frames has columns c("b1", "a1", "c1"), they'll still end up in the right place in bigmat.

Thanks, this works perfectly with the toy dataset, however, I need to make it work with my data. I will update you.

@fiodeno given that you have two answers, if there are significant changes between your example and your real data, I would suggest that rather than updating your question you ask another one. See this meta thread on chameleon questions.

I understand your point, but creating a new question is pointless in this case. What is the names are not in the same order? I can even update my initial question, if you prefer.

@fiodeno I'm not saying never edit questions - it depends how significant the change is, which I can't say as I don't know what it is. FWIW this works regardless of the order of the names.

Use plyr::rbind.fill:
plyr::rbind.fill(IO)

          a1       b1         c1          a2       b2        c2         a3       b3        c3
1  0.5547427 1.071754 -2.7006666          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
2 -0.1319744 1.105724 -1.3260365          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
3 -0.5326793 2.943132 -0.5305472          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
4         NA       NA         NA -0.07965929 5.012082 -3.793977         NA       NA        NA
5         NA       NA         NA -0.36112182 6.813468  1.024444         NA       NA        NA
6         NA       NA         NA -1.50896289 4.261591 -5.803245         NA       NA        NA
7         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -0.2672665 9.583140 -2.363130
8         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -2.2510105 9.608332 -3.368700
9         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -1.6999382 8.198382  4.603975


dplyr::bind_rows(IO)

           a1       b1         c1          a2       b2        c2         a3       b3        c3
a1  0.5547427 1.071754 -2.7006666          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
b1 -0.1319744 1.105724 -1.3260365          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
c1 -0.5326793 2.943132 -0.5305472          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
a2         NA       NA         NA -0.07965929 5.012082 -3.793977         NA       NA        NA
b2         NA       NA         NA -0.36112182 6.813468  1.024444         NA       NA        NA
c2         NA       NA         NA -1.50896289 4.261591 -5.803245         NA       NA        NA
a3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -0.2672665 9.583140 -2.363130
b3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -2.2510105 9.608332 -3.368700
c3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -1.6999382 8.198382  4.603975

in base R:
Reduce(\(x,y)merge(x,y,all = TRUE, sort = FALSE), lapply(IO, \(x)cbind(id=rownames(x),x)))

  id         a1       b1         c1          a2       b2        c2         a3       b3        c3
1 a1  0.5547427 1.071754 -2.7006666          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
2 b1 -0.1319744 1.105724 -1.3260365          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
3 c1 -0.5326793 2.943132 -0.5305472          NA       NA        NA         NA       NA        NA
4 a2         NA       NA         NA -0.07965929 5.012082 -3.793977         NA       NA        NA
5 b2         NA       NA         NA -0.36112182 6.813468  1.024444         NA       NA        NA
6 c2         NA       NA         NA -1.50896289 4.261591 -5.803245         NA       NA        NA
7 a3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -0.2672665 9.583140 -2.363130
8 b3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -2.2510105 9.608332 -3.368700
9 c3         NA       NA         NA          NA       NA        NA -1.6999382 8.198382  4.603975

